# Remove Validation Errors on Second Step of Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a multi-step JavaScript form that automatically displays the validation error messages for all fields on the second step when you click the first button to proceed to the second step of the form. I'd like to have the validation error messages in place, but I only want them to trigger if a user attempts to submit the form without filling out the required fields. Please see the form code here:

```
<div class="pricing-table sc-lead-form-homepage">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="plan most-popular">
        <div class="plan-ribbon-wrapper">
            <div class="plan-ribbon">100% Free</div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Quick & Easy Quote</strong></h3>                            

        <form class="registration-form" id="leadForm" onsubmit="return validateLeadForm() && trackSubmit()">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">Choose Your Bond:</h4></label></span>                
                            <select class="form-control" id="leadBondRequest">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Select the bond type</option>
                                <optgroup label="License & Permit / Misc. Bonds">
                                    <option value="2">Auto Dealer Bond</option>
                                    <option value="2">Contractor License Bond</option>
                                    <option value="2">Freight Broker BMC-84 Bond</option>
                                    <option value="2">Other License / Misc. Bond</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Construction & Service Contracts (non-license)">
                                    <option value="1">Bid Bond</option>
                                    <option value="1">Performance Bond</option>
                                    <option value="1">Service Contract</option>
                                    <option value="1">Other Construction (non-license)</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                            <span id="leadBondRequestMsg" class="leadErrMsg"/>                                                  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">Bond Amount:</h4></label></span>
                            <input type="text" id="leadBondAmount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your bond amount" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event,"leadBondAmountMsg");' onBlur="validateEle(this)" onfocus="focusEle(this)"/>
                            <span id="leadBondAmountMsg" class="leadErrMsg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">Email to Send Your Quote:</h4></label></span>
                            <input type="text" id="leadEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="We'll never share your information!" onBlur="validateEle(this)"/>
                            <span id="leadEmailMsg" class="leadErrMsg"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button class="sc-lead-form-btn btn-next">Get Your Free Quote!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">First Name:</h4></label></span>
                            <input type="text" id="leadFName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your first name" onBlur="validateEle(this)"/>
                            <span id="leadFNameMsg" class="leadErrMsg"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">Last Name:</h4></label></span>
                            <input type="text" id="leadLName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your last name" onBlur="validateEle(this)"/>
                            <span id="leadLNameMsg" class="leadErrMsg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">Company Name:</h4></label></span>
                            <input type="text" id="leadCompany" class="form-control" placeholder="Your company name" onBlur="validateEle(this)"/>
                            <span id="leadCompanyMsg" class="leadErrMsg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="leadSubTitle"><label><h4 class="get-started-form">Phone Number:</h4></label></span>
                            <input type="text" id="leadPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="(___) ___-____" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event,"leadPhoneMsg");' onBlur="validateEle(this)" onfocus="focusEle(this)"/>
                            <span id="leadPhoneMsg" class="leadErrMsg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">

                    <button type="submit" id="sclead" class="sc-lead-form-btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">Send Your Quote Now!</button>

                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px;" src="/img/powered-by-sc.png">
                    <p class="leadText">Are you an insurance agent? If so <a onclick="scLead('registerSubBroker=true')">register your agency</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, [here's a link](https://www.suretycloud.com/SuretyCloud/js/leadForm.js) to the js file that performs the validation (I won't copy/paste the code since it's so long).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to ensure the error messages don't display by default when you proceed to the second step of the form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you create a fiddle for us to troubleshoot? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I tried inputting all of the code the form uses using a fiddle (my first time using it) and everything seems to be functioning normally except for the validation error messages, as they're missing. Please see here: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/wdto4ufj/4/

Comment: So I determined that since the first button "type" wasn't defined, the default of "submit" was being applied which caused the error messages on the second step. However, when I apply type="button" to the first button, the validation errors no longer appear on the first step when you try to submit the form without filling out the fields. Any ideas on how to keep the type="button" in place on the first button, while having the error messages display if you try to submit the first step of the form without info?

Comment: Anyone know how the js in the fiddle above could be edited to accomplish this? I've tried tinkering myself with no success.

Comment: Sorry, away from the PC for a few days... catching up with email here at work; If I find sometime later today, I will have a good look at your issue

Comment: Hey, I notice the button is calling a function called `validateLeadForm` but the function is not found in the code you added to the fiddle - also can you minimize your fiddle to an [mcve]... there is a lot of code that is not needed to troubleshoot form validation

Comment: Hey ochi. The validateLeadForm is called in the js. Do you see it? See here [link]https://jsfiddle.net/wdto4ufj/13/. Also, I believe the code I included is needed for troubleshooting, as the js code for the multi-step form and the form validation is needed to make the form function as intended.